# Facebook Graph API Error - feed story publishing is disabled

Tags: facebook, feed, sharing

We have an app on Facebook that allows us to share our content to user's feed. Since some time ago Facebook banned out application access to user's wall and replies to us with error

`Feed sharing is disabled for this application`

All needed permissions are correctly asked by the app and sharing to user's feed worked for us using Graph API.

I strongly need to know how to contact with Facebook support and solve this issue because users of our service are very disappointed with this issue and keep reporting it to us. And there is no way to send direct email to Facebook support because of their "knowledge help gate".

Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/appeal

Comment: thank you very much, I think this is the page I was looking for. But it returns 404 when I try to send the appeal. Anyway, as I understand it is the only way to get Facebook feedback regarding the app and your comment helped very much.